# System of Equations- using profits

Tags: linear-algebra, functions

Question: Keller industries' profits were up **$20,000**  this year over last year. This was an increase of **25%**.

a. Let *T* represent the profit this year and *L* the profit from last year and write a system of equations that can be used to determine the profits.

b. Which method would be most efficient to solve this system (addition method or substitution method)? Explain

c.Using your system to determine the profit for this year and last year.

**Is this two different equations for both the profit made this year and the profit made last year? **

Comment: Can you please share your thoughts and efforts, and explain what you're having difficulty with?

Comment: My thoughts on this problem is I have a difficult time with formulating system of equations. I was thinking that T(20,000)-L

Comment: Is this two different equations for both the profit made in the this year and the profit made last year?

Comment: Could **T(20,000)+0.25** and could **L(20,000)-0.25**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two pieces of information are given:

$\bullet$ This year's profit is $\$20000$ more than last year's profit.
$\bullet$ The increase is $25\%$.

You should write both in equation form. Then you get a system of two equations with two variables, which you can solve.